# What does 些 mean when it's combined with 什麼?

Tags: usage

I found [this sentence on tatoeba.org](http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/458549):

> 我就是不知道說些什麼。
>
> I just don't know what to say.

I understand most of the sentence, but what is "些" doing there? I've always seen it used to mean "a few".

Comment: +1 I was getting tired of seeing so much jianti on here...

Comment: I'm chinese. Pyko'S answer is correct.

Comment: sorry for hijacking a question for private message: i just noticed that we both have John Skeet in our g+ circles...have you met him personally?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @Laguna, but no, I've never met him personally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct, "些" is used to mean "a few" and it also applies in the example you gave above - ie. you can't even find 'a few' words to say.

I believe you can also leave out "些" and it will still mean almost the same thing. To me, with/without "些" the sentence means the same thing but has a slightly different emphasis/tone to it.

For me, with "些" it feels a bit 'softer'...as if you are genuinely out of words (maybe you saw something and suddenly lost for words); whilst without "些" it sounds like you are frustrated (someone has annoyed you, did something stupid) and you don't know how to comment/what to say to them.

ps. I would personally say:

> 我就是不知道要說(些)什麼

pps. I'm also learning Chinese, so confirmation from someone who is a native speaker would be nice :)